# Importing Material-UI Components

Tags: reactjs, materialize, material-ui

I've been working with a lot of Material-UI components recently, and for the most part, they are pretty easy to import. I'm starting to find that the documentation on http://www.material-ui.com/ is not very good when it comes to showing where to import components from.

For example, to import the List component, one needs to import from material-ui/lib/lists/list. Is there a known dictionary with these component and import paths associated? It gets quite frustrating to not be able to import the necessary components, even though they do seem to follow a fairly common path, i.e., material-ui/lib/.

It doesn't look like the repo on GitHub contains the true paths to the components, so better documentation might be the answer.

Thanks!

Comment: All of the examples have the correct import paths, no?

Comment: Unfortunately, they do not. Take http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/list for example. If you try to import the List component with the path given, you will get an error from Javascript. I had to import List using 'material-ui/lib/lists/list'.

Comment: Make sure you are viewing the documentation for the correct version. The paths changed between 0.14 and 0.15. Looks like [you might be on v0.14](http://www.material-ui.com/v0.14.4/#/components/list).

Comment: Good suggestion, I confirmed I'm on version 0.15. This import line (import {List, ListItem} from 'material-ui/List';) comes straight from the simple list example on http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/list

Comment: Looking at [the source](https://github.com/callemall/material-ui/blob/master/src/List/index.js), that should work. Can you post an example that doesn't?

Comment: I can't really post an example, but when I had 'import {List, ListItem} from 'material-ui/List', I received a console error saying "Cannot find module "material-ui/List"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example code in the docs is the very code that is run to create the examples. The imports shown there are the imports actually used by that code (for the version of Material-UI you are checking the docs for).

If an import isn't working, it is likely that either you're using a different version of Material-UI to that for which you are looking at the docs, or you have a typo in your import.

> I had to import List using 'material-ui/lib/lists/list'

This confirms that your installed version of Material-UI is 0.15.0-alpha.2 or prior. We moved to the new directory structure in beta.1: https://github.com/callemall/material-ui/releases/tag/v0.15.0-beta.1, thanks to this PR: https://github.com/callemall/material-ui/pull/3749

Comment: Thank you for the information, Matt. There is still something that doesn't make sense to me when it comes to importing components, but I'm usually able to determine how to get the import working. I'll look into the structure changes and perhaps we can move to the beta 1 version sometime soon.

Comment: Please could you mark as answered? This still shows in the review queue.